# filter list of objects by filtering a list of objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-filters

I have two models ItemCategory and Item, I want to filter the list of ItemCategory by filtering **is_published** field of item.

```
class ItemCategory(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='item-category', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'category: ' + self.category_name


class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_desc = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField()

    item_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='item-images')
    num_of_items_available = models.IntegerField()

    category_name = models.ForeignKey(ItemCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='items')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'item: ' + self.item_name
```

Here is my approach but didn't get any success.

```
class ItemCategoryView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = ItemCategoryListSerializer

    def list(self, request, format=None):

        queryset = ItemCategory.objects.filter(items__in=Item.objects.filter(is_published=True))

        serializer = ItemCategorySerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

ItemCategorySerializer looks like this

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('pk', 'item_name', 'item_desc', 'price', 'item_image', 'num_of_items_available',
              'category_name', 'is_published')


class ItemCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ItemCategory
        fields = ('pk', 'category_name', 'category_image',  'items')
```

Can anyone tell my how i can approach to this problem?

**Edit**

I have tried this two queries

> queryset = ItemCategory.objects.filter(items__in=Item.objects.filter(is_published=True)) queryset = ItemCategory.objects.filter(items__is_published=True)

I think both this query work but not in the way i want. Heres how it works now.

It returns list of ItemCategory where any list of item with **is_published** = True. Say There are 3 categories(A, B , C) and each category has 3 list of item (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3). and let all have **is_published** = False except C3.

So now the query result is something like this. It returns only C Category with all the list item C1, C2, C3. which is not the desired result. I should be getting only C3 since this is the only published Item.

Comment: Try this: `queryset = ItemCategory.objects.filter(items__is_published=True)` this return ItemCategory with published items.

Comment: no it doesn't. I tried it

Comment: Weird.. any errors or it works but don't return what you want?

Comment: Hey @neverwalkaloner it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are very welcome! I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `filter` and `prefetch_related`:

```
queryset = ItemCategory.objects.filter(items__is_published=True).prefet‌​ch_related(Prefetch(‌​"items", queryset=Item.objects.fiter(is_published=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to filter them items before return the the category itself.

1. Filter all published items.
2. Filter all categories by published items.

Maybe you can use this method, but previously I suggest you to use the `QuerySet` manager.

**1. `models.py`**

```
class ItemCategory(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='item-category', null=True)

    def get_published_items(self):
        """
        return all items contains with this single Category.
        """
        return Item.objects.published().filter(category_name__pk=self.pk)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'category: ' + self.category_name


class ItemQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def published(self):
        return self.filter(is_published=True)

    def unpublished(self):
        return self.filter(is_published=False)


class Item(models.Model):
    ....
    category_name = models.ForeignKey(
      ItemCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
      null=True, related_name='items')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = ItemQuerySet.as_manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'item: ' + self.item_name
```

**2. views.py**

```
class ItemCategoryView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = ItemCategoryListSerializer

    def list(self, request, format=None):
        # find all categories first
        published_categories_by_items = [ c.category_name for c in Item.objects.published() ]
        # then, filter the categories itself.
        queryset = ItemCategory.objects.filter(pk__in=[ c.pk for c in published_categories_by_items]).distinct()

        serializer = ItemCategorySerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```